# get_it injection fails for unknown reason on injecting Cubit

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am building an application which uses an authentication token to make requests to the API. The expiry of a token is 1 hour so I need to refresh it every hour. I use Dio and added an interceptor for the refresh token method. But when I do, the whole app crashes and all my injections fail to build. I also use a TokenInterceptor and LocaleInterceptor, which are build up similar but don't crash.

The only difference is that they use a StorageCubit, which only gets a SharedPreferences instance injected. The AuthCubit (where the RefreshTokenInterceptor relies on) gets 2 usecases injected and the StorageCubit.

This is the error I receive for every injection:

```
flutter: Error while creating AuthRemoteDataSource
flutter: Stack trace:
 #0      _GetItImplementation._findFirstFactoryByNameAndTypeOrNull (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:324:3)
#1      _GetItImplementation._findFactoryByNameAndType (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:369:9)
#2      _GetItImplementation.get (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:393:29)
#3      _GetItImplementation.call (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:430:12)
#4      init.<anonymous closure> (package:***/app/injection.dart:105:9)
#5      _ServiceFactory.getObject (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:160:41)
#6      _GetItImplementation.get (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:409:34)
#7      _GetItImplementation.call (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:430:12)
#8      init.<anonymous closure> (package:coinmerce_c2/app/injection.dart:90:27)
#9      _ServiceFactory.getObject (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:160:41)
#10     _GetItImplementation.get (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:409:34)
#11     _GetItImplementation.call (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:430:12)
#12     init.<anonymous cl<…>
```

When I commented out the AuthCubit in my RefreshTokenProvider (the interceptor uses the provider to actually do things, and the interceptor only adds the value received from the provider into the DIO call just to keep things clean) every injection gets build without any issues.

This is my RefreshTokenProvider:

```
class RefreshTokenProvider {
  final AuthCubit authCubit;

  RefreshTokenProvider(
    this.authCubit,
  );

  Future<String> refreshToken() async {
    try {
      final int _tokenInStorageExpiry = await authCubit.getTokenExpiry();

      final now = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

      //refreshes token if token is expired
      if (now >= _tokenInStorageExpiry) {
        await authCubit.refreshToken();
      }

      final String refreshedTokenInStorage = await authCubit.getToken();

      return refreshedTokenInStorage;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

This is my AuthCubit:

```
part 'auth_state.dart';

class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
  final UserLoginUsecase userLoginUsecase;
  final RefreshTokenUsecase refreshTokenUsecase;
  final StorageCubit storage;

  AuthCubit({
    required this.userLoginUsecase,
    required this.refreshTokenUsecase,
    required this.storage,
  }) : super(
          const AuthState(),
        );

  Future<void> userLogin({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    String? twoFactor,
  }) async {
    try {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.loading),
      );

      final failureOrLogin = await userLoginUsecase(Params(
        email: email,
        password: password,
        twoFactor: twoFactor,
      ));

      _eitherLoadedOrFailureStateUserLogin(failureOrLogin);
    } on ServerFailure {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: AuthStatus.failure,
          exception: CoException(message: SERVER_FAILURE_TEXT),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> refreshToken() async {
    try {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.loading),
      );

      final failureOrRefreshToken = await refreshTokenUsecase(
        NoParams(),
      );

      _eitherLoadedOrFailureStateRefreshToken(failureOrRefreshToken);
    } on ServerFailure {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: AuthStatus.failure,
          exception: CoException(message: SERVER_FAILURE_TEXT),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void _eitherLoadedOrFailureStateUserLogin(
    Either<Failure, Login> failureOrLogin,
  ) async {
    failureOrLogin.fold(
      (failure) => emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: AuthStatus.failure,
          exception: CoException(message: failure.message),
        ),
      ),
      (login) => saveToken(
        token: login.token,
        tokenExpired: login.tokenExpired,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _eitherLoadedOrFailureStateRefreshToken(
    Either<Failure, RefreshToken> failureOrRefreshToken,
  ) async {
    failureOrRefreshToken.fold(
      (failure) => emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: AuthStatus.failure,
          exception: CoException(message: failure.message),
        ),
      ),
      (refreshToken) => saveToken(
        token: refreshToken.token,
        tokenExpired: refreshToken.tokenExpired,
      ),
    );
  }

  void saveToken({required String token, required int tokenExpired}) async {
    try {
      final key = crypt.Key.fromUtf8('******');
      final iv = crypt.IV.fromLength(16);

      final encrypter = await crypt.Encrypter(
        crypt.AES(
          key,
          mode: crypt.AESMode.ecb,
        ),
      );

      final encryptedToken = await encrypter.encrypt(token, iv: iv).base64;

      await storage.saveString('token', encryptedToken);
      await storage.saveInt('token_expired', tokenExpired);

      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.success),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    try {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.loading),
      );
      await storage.removeFromStorage('token');
      await storage.removeFromStorage('pin');
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.success),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: AuthStatus.failure,
          exception: CoException(message: UNCAUGHT_FAILURE_TEXT),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> savePin(String pincode) async {
    try {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.loading),
      );
      await storage.saveString('pin', pincode);
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.success),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: AuthStatus.failure,
          exception: CoException(message: UNCAUGHT_FAILURE_TEXT),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<String> getToken() async {
    final key = crypt.Key.fromUtf8('*******');
    final iv = crypt.IV.fromLength(16);

    final encrypter = await crypt.Encrypter(
      crypt.AES(key, mode: crypt.AESMode.ecb, padding: null),
    );

    try {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.loading),
      );
      final String token = await storage.getString('token');

      final String decryptedToken = await encrypter.decrypt64(token, iv: iv);

      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.success),
      );

      return decryptedToken;
    } catch (e) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: AuthStatus.failure,
          exception: CoException(message: UNCAUGHT_FAILURE_TEXT),
        ),
      );
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<int> getTokenExpiry() async {
    try {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.loading),
      );
      final int tokenExpired = await storage.getValue('token_expired');
      emit(
        state.copyWith(status: AuthStatus.success),
      );

      return tokenExpired;
    } catch (e) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: AuthStatus.failure,
          exception: CoException(message: UNCAUGHT_FAILURE_TEXT),
        ),
      );
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my injection file, which gets initialised in main.dart as first:

```
final sl = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> init() async {
  //! Features - Landing
  //cubit
  sl.registerFactory(
    () => LandingCubit(
      getAccountUsecase: sl(),
    ),
  );

  //usecases
  sl.registerLazySingleton(
    () => GetAccountUsecase(
      repository: sl(),
    ),
  );

  //repositories
  sl.registerLazySingleton<GetAccountRepository>(
    () => GetAccountRepositoryImpl(
      networkInfo: sl(),
      remoteDataSource: sl(),
    ),
  );

  //data source
  sl.registerLazySingleton<GetAccountRemoteDataSource>(
    () => GetAccountRemoteDataSourceImpl(
      sl(),
    ),
  );

  //! Features - Auth

  //usecases
  sl.registerLazySingleton(
    () => UserLoginUsecase(
      repository: sl(),
    ),
  );

  sl.registerLazySingleton(
    () => RefreshTokenUsecase(
      repository: sl(),
    ),
  );

  //repositories
  sl.registerLazySingleton<LoginRepository>(
    () => LoginRepositoryImpl(
      remoteDataSource: sl(),
      networkInfo: sl(),
    ),
  );

  sl.registerLazySingleton<RefreshTokenRepository>(
    () => RefreshTokenRepositoryImpl(
      remoteDataSource: sl(),
      networkInfo: sl(),
    ),
  );

  //data source
  sl.registerLazySingleton<AuthRemoteDataSource>(
    () => AuthRemoteDataSourceImpl(
      sl(),
    ),
  );

  //cubit
  sl.registerFactory(
    () => AuthCubit(
      userLoginUsecase: sl(),
      refreshTokenUsecase: sl(),
      storage: sl(),
    ),
  );

  //! Features - Controls
  //bloc
  sl.registerFactory(
    () => ControlsCubit(
      authCubit: sl(),
    ),
  );

  //! Features - Common

  //Storage cubit
  sl.registerFactory(
    () => StorageCubit(
      prefs: sl(),
    ),
  );

  //! Core
  sl.registerFactory(
    () => InputValidationCubit(),
  );

  //!platform
  sl.registerLazySingleton<NetworkInfo>(
    () => NetworkInfoImpl(
      sl(),
    ),
  );

  //!Providers
  sl.registerLazySingleton(
    () => RefreshTokenProvider(
      sl(),
    ),
  );

  sl.registerLazySingleton(
    () => LocaleProvider(
      sl(),
    ),
  );

  sl.registerLazySingleton(
    () => TokenProvider(
      sl(),
    ),
  );

  //!Data
  //dio client
  sl.registerLazySingleton<Dio>(
    () => DioClient().getDio(),
  );

  //! External
  final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  sl.registerLazySingleton(
    () => sharedPreferences,
  );

  sl.registerLazySingleton(
    () => Connectivity(),
  );

  sl.registerLazySingleton(
    () => http.Client(),
  );
}
```

Does anyone now why this is happening or what I am doing wrong / overseeing? If you need more info please let me know.

Kind regards,
Niek